# Can I return an index as if statement in one line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
a = [12, 3, 4, 6, 7, 13, 21]
label = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0] 
print([float(i) for i in a if label[i] == 1])
```

I just want to return the index of label which is 1, and then the index used for `a` to search a new list, so the result should be `[12, 3, 4, 7, 13]`.

Can I write this in one line? Now my code problem is on `i`, I know it returns the item of `a`, not an index, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is not really index for `label`, you can use `zip` to loop through `a` and `label` in parallel, and pick `a` if label is `1`:

```
[i for i, l in zip(a, label) if l == 1]
# [12, 3, 4, 7, 13]
```

Answer (score 2):

With `enumerate`, you can access both values and counters within list comprehension.

```
[a[i] for i, v in enumerate(label) if v == 1]
#[12, 3, 4, 7, 13]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the lists into `numpy` array and use `boolean indexing`

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([12,3,4,6,7,13,21])
label = np.array([1,1,1,0,1,1,0])

print(a[label == 1])
>> [12  3  4  7 13]
```